# Using NSPredicate to filter based on multiple keys (NOT values for key)

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsarray, nspredicate

I have the following NSArray containing NSDictionary(s):

```
NSArray *data = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:
                 [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[NSNumber numberWithInt:1], @"bill", [NSNumber numberWithInt:2], @"joe", nil],
                 [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[NSNumber numberWithInt:3], @"bill", [NSNumber numberWithInt:4], @"joe", [NSNumber numberWithInt:5], @"jenny", nil],
                 [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[NSNumber numberWithInt:6], @"joe", [NSNumber numberWithInt:1], @"jenny", nil],
                 nil];
```

I am wanting to create a filtered NSArray that only contains objects where the NSDictionary matches multiple 'keys' using NSPredicate.

For example:

- filter the array to only contain the NSDictionary objects that have keys "bill" and "joe" [desired result: new NSArray would contain the *first* two NSDictionary objects]
- filter the array to only contain the NSDictionary objects that have keys "joe" and "jenny" [desired result: new NSArray would contain the *last* two NSDictionary objects]

Can anyone please explain the format of the NSPredicate to achieve this?

Edit:
I can achieve a similar outcome to desired NSPredicate using:

```
NSMutableArray *filteredSet = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:[data count]];
NSString *keySearch1 = [NSString stringWithString:@"bill"];
NSString *keySearch2 = [NSString stringWithString:@"joe"];

for (NSDictionary *currentDict in data){
    // objectForKey will return nil if a key doesn't exists.
    if ([currentDict objectForKey:keySearch1] && [currentDict objectForKey:keySearch2]){
        [filteredSet addObject:currentDict];
    }
}

NSLog(@"filteredSet: %@", filteredSet);
```

I'm imagining NSPredicate would be more elegant if one exists?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

they only way I know is to combine two conditions like "'value1' IN list AND 'value2' IN list"

self.@allKeys should return all the keys of the dictionary (self is each dictionary in your array). If you don't write it with the prefix @ then the dictionary will just look for a key that is "allKeys" instead of the method "- (NSArray*) allKeys"

The code:

```
NSArray* billAndJoe = [data filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"%@ IN self.@allKeys AND %@ IN self.@allKeys" , @"bill",@"joe" ]];


NSArray* joeAndJenny = [data filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"%@ IN self.@allKeys AND %@ IN self.@allKeys" , @"joe",@"jenny" ]]
```

Comment: He could also use NSCompoundPredicate's `+andPredicateWithSubpredicates:` instead of hardcoding only 2 choices.

Comment: Thanks.  I'll try this in the morning.  The code is looking like what I want though!

Comment: Ok .. finally got back to this.  The code works, just need to make sure it's alloc init-ed:  `NSArray* billAndJoe = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray: [NSArray arrayWithArray:[data filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"%@ IN self.@allKeys AND %@ IN self.@allKeys" , @"bill",@"joe" ]]]];`

Comment: Actually scrap that - It works exactly as Alexander wrote above.  [get's next cup of coffee ..].

Answer (score 5):

Since a dictionary just returns `nil` if you ask for a value of a non-existing key, it is enough to specify that the value should be non-nil. A format like the following should cover your first case:

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat: @"%K != nil AND %K != nil", @"bill", @"joe"]
```

The second case, with "joe" and "jenny" follows a similar pattern, of course.