# Get list of Values for an NSArray of NSDictionary

Tags: objective-c, nsarray, nsdictionary, nspredicate

I've got the following NSArray :

```
NSArray myArray = @[@{@300:@"5 min"},
                    @{@900:@"15 min"},
                    @{@1800:@"30 min"},
                    @{@3600:@"1 hour"}];
```

I want the list of value of my dictionaries :

```
@[@"5 min",@"15 min",@"30 min",@"1 hour"]
```

And the list of key of my dictionaries :

```
@[@300, @900, @1800, @3600]
```

What is the best way to do that ? I was thinking about predicate, but I don't know how to use it ?

Comment: What's the point of multiple dictionaries if the keys are already unique? A simple dictionary would hold all this info just fine and you could retrieve your keys/values with the relevant methods.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10980618/using-nspredicate-to-filter-based-on-multiple-keys-not-values-for-key

Comment: Interesting question, but the obligatory counter-question is: What have you tried? Show us what you have done so far and why it didn't work out as planned.

Comment: I did tried anything yet, but I'm pretty sure it it possible by iterating on the NSArray and filling a new NSArray for each dictionary. But I think there is a lighter way to do it.

Comment: @Tommecpe the reason I asked for what you have tried so far is - apart from doing some effort first is the right thing to do - it helps understand the direction you're taking, and weeds out people who just use SO to get other people write their software for them to their specs. Anyway, posted an answer that I _think_ is what you are looking for.

Comment: @Alladinian right ! I didn't think about it !! if will be more simple.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Without some code to show how you'd want to go about this it is difficult to be sure exactly what you are after, and there is a bit of confusion in the question.

First, a predicate is exactly that - a statement that can be proven true or false. Predicates are hence used in logic expressions, including those employed implicitly in database queries - such as Core Data.

That is *not* what you want, if I read your question correctly. What you want is to reduce the complexity of your data model, removing some excess (one would hope) information in the process. A sort of flattening of an array of dictionaries.

Fair enough.

I can also see how the confusion with predicates came about - they are most often constructed using Key-Value Coding. KVC, as it is also known, is a very powerful technique that can accomplish what you are after. It just does not have much to do with a logic statement.

Having cleared that up, with KVC you can do what you want, and with minimal fuss. It goes  like this:

```
NSArray *values = [myArray valueForKeyPath: @"@unionOfArrays.@allValues"];

NSArray *keys   = [myArray valueForKeyPath: @"@unionOfArrays.@allKeys"];
```

A brief explanation might be in order:

The results that we want are

1. All the values (or keys) of each dictionary, obtaining an array of arrays of values (or keys)
2. Then we want to flatten these arrays into a single array.

To obtain all values (or keys) from a dictionary using KVC, the special key is `@allValues` or `@allKeys`, respectively.

The `@unionOfArrays` operator makes a union of the arrays obtained from the expression that follows it, i.e., flattens it into the array you wanted.

The price you pay for this coding simplicity is that you have to use KVC key paths with collection operators, which are just strings in your code. You therefore lose any help from the compiler with syntax and it doesn't check that the keys you enter exist in the objects. Similarly, the debugger and error messages are unhelpful if you mistype or use the wrong operator, for instance.

Comment: Thank you very much for this very complete response ! I'm not a an of KVC for the reason you explain : "you've got just strings in your code" and so debugging is harder. But a lot of powerful tool in objective c use strings :(

Comment: I can't tell you how much i love this answer! Many thanks! :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use dictionary property allValues to get all values of dictionary.

Try this code in your case

```
NSArray *myArray = @[@{@300:@"5 min"},
                     @{@900:@"15 min"},
                     @{@1800:@"30 min"},
                     @{@3600:@"1 hour"}];
NSMutableArray *arr = [NSMutableArray array];
for (NSDictionary *dict in myArray) {
    [arr addObject:[[dict allValues] objectAtIndex:0]];
}
NSLog(@"%@",arr);
```

Note : Make sure you have only one value in each dictionary.
it will return

[

5 min,

15 min,

30 min,

1 hour

]

Answer (score 1):

@johnyu's answers is technically correct, but I don't see any reason to include the secondary loop, especially if the data structure will remain the same.

```
NSArray *myArray = @[@{@300:@"5 min"},
                     @{@900:@"15 min"},
                     @{@1800:@"30 min"},
                     @{@3600:@"1 hour"}];

NSMutableArray *arrayOfValues = [NSMutableArray new];
NSMutableArray *arrayOfKeys = [NSMutableArray new];

for (NSDictionary *dictionary in myArray) {
    [arrayOfValues addObject:dictionary.allValues[0]];
    [arrayOfKeys addObject:dictionary.allKeys[0]];
}

NSLog(@"%@",arrayOfKeys);
NSLog(@"%@",arrayOfValues);
```

Comment: +1. Almost. :P You make an array with a single object, and that object is array. :) But indeed, allValues and allKeys methods seem to be the better way to go. It should be 2 NSArrays that are not explicitly allocated in this code, and assigning the values should be like arrayOfValues = [dictrionary allValues];

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
NSArray *myArray = @[@{@300:@"5 min"},
                    @{@900:@"15 min"},
                    @{@1800:@"30 min"},
                    @{@3600:@"1 hour"}];
NSMutableArray *keyArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
NSMutableArray *valueArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
for (NSDictionary *dictionary in myArray) {
    for (NSString *key in dictionary) {
        [keyArray addObject:key];
        [valueArray addObject:[dictionary objectForKey:key]];
    }
}
```

Comment: That was my first thought, but it is king of old school, I ther a way to do that with `Predicate` ?

Comment: I've tried your solution and It work very well. If I can't find a Predicat's solution I will make it as the proper solution