# iOS SearchViewController with two filters

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios8, nsarray, uisearchbar

I have an array with two keys and values at each index and In my tableview,  one value for key i am passing to text and other to detail text.

```
cell.textLabel.text = [[ar1 objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"a"];
cell.detailTextLabel.text  = [[ar1 objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"b"];
```

Now I want to search from any of these values and again print the search values to the table.

I am using the search filter but search filter gives me array with only one value for key either `a` or 'b'

```
- (void)filterContentForSearchText:(NSString*)searchText scope:(NSString*)scope
{
 NSPredicate *resultPredicate = [NSPredicate
                                predicateWithFormat:@"(SELF BEGINSWITH[cd] %@) OR (SELF BEGINSWITH[cd] %@)",
                                searchText];
searchResults = [[ar1 valueForKey:@"a"] filteredArrayUsingPredicate:resultPredicate];
if(searchResults.count ==0){
     searchResults = [[ar1 valueForKey:@"b"] filteredArrayUsingPredicate:resultPredicate];\

//how do i add values for a and b corresponding key at a time
// i tried this but crashing
// searchResults = [[ar1 valueForKey:@"a"],[ar1 valueForKey:@"b"]] filteredArrayUsingPredicate:resultPredicate];

}
}
```

help me to get values for corresponding a and b in searchResult array.

Comment: Pick up the dictionary

Comment: @srinivasn where to use?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10980618/using-nspredicate-to-filter-based-on-multiple-keys-not-values-for-key

Comment: You got it ? your problem is solve

Comment: yes i  tried but problem is in each iteration of dictionary i will have two key values and in filtered array multiple values.. now how do i check for corresponding

Comment: how do i check for corresponding  means

Comment: you got the dictionaries in that dictionaries have contain corresponding values

Comment: @thanks worked.. In dictionary i needed to run two loops to match for both

Comment: Welcome , Go head and enjoy the programming